# Django - Template chain tags

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to use a `firstof` in a `with` like

```
<div>
  {% with variable = firstof variable1 variable2 %}</div>
  {{ variable }}
  {% endwith %}
</div>
```

But of course I'm getting

> u'with' received an invalid token: u'variable1'

Is there another way to use these 2 tags together ?

Comment: does it not work? {% with variable = variable1 or variable2 %}

Comment: Gives "invalid token or" As `with` will take space as separators for parsing tokens

Comment: This still doesn't work in 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign `firstof` to a variable like this, sadly (see [this thread on django-users](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/f5a90aa42dd43b47?pli=1)). You'd need to write [your own custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).